# Order rows of binary values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sorting

I have some numpy arrays that looks like this:

```
[[0,0,1],
 [0,1,0],
 [0,0,0]]

[[0,0,1],
 [0,0,0],
 [0,1,0]]
```

I want to order the rows so that every time I get a different array, it is ordered consistently. So for the two arrays shown above, I want to get the same result:

```
[[0,0,0],
 [0,0,1],
 [0,1,0]]
```

I thought about doing it as a data frame merging the columns and then sorting but I am not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: why not numpy sort?

Comment: wouldn't numpy sort set [0,1,0] and [0,0,1] to [0,0,1] ? Or how would you apply it ?

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood your question, np.sort won't work

Comment: How big are the arrays? Do they always have say less than 32 columns?

Comment: Ideally, I would like it to work with more, but I can limit the number and it would still be very helpful

Comment: Please define exactly what should happen. It is not clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`np.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html):

```
a[np.lexsort(a.T[::-1])]
```

Comment: man you rock! i still remember the long time you invested in answering my question long ago! go on brother!